# Retrieve value from AndroidManifest file in ant

Tags: android, xml, ant

i am trying to retrieve the versionName from a androidManifest xml file and unable to do so via ant.

Here is what i have tried:

```
<xmlproperty file="AndroidManifest.xml"/>

<echo>android manifest test ${manifest.android:versionName} ${android.android:versionName} ${android:versionName}</echo>
```

i tried 3 combinations and all 3 fail to output the versionName

snippet of my manifest file below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.hello.main" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="20">

    <application

...

<activity

....
```

Any suggestions?

i simply want to retrieve the value 20 from android:versionName="20"

Comment: have u tried it as `<xpath input="AndroidManifest.xml" expression="/manifest/@android:versionName" output="version.name" default="0.0.0.0"/>  
<echo>android manifest test version.name=${version.name}</echo>`

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick

```
<xmlproperty file="AndroidManifest.xml" collapseAttributes="true"/>
```

if you want to treat attribute values as elements use the above